# Split collection linq entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a PropertyValues entity which reperesent product properties:

```
public enum Property { Color = 1, Brand, Size }

public class PropertyValue
{
    public int PropertyValueId { get; set; }
    public Property PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public PropertyValue()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
}
```

Cause we have end sequnce of product properties i created an enum Property which keep properties.
I'm trying to achieve following result - to split collection depending on properties. Where the values are an another Dictionary

```
        Dictionary<Property, Dictionary<int, string>> dict = new Dictionary<Property, Dictionary<int, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<Property, Dictionary<int, string>>()
            {
                {
                    Property.Color,
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>()
                    {
                        { 5, "white" }, // ProperyValueId, Value
                        { 6, "green"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have been looked aside GroupBy and SelectMany, but didn't find a way.
For now i have following:

```
            var query = await db.PropertyValues
            .OrderBy(prop => prop.PropertyId)
            .Where(prop => prop.PropertyId == Property.Brand)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(prop => prop.PropertyValueId, prop => prop.Value);

        Dictionary<Property, Dictionary<int, string>> properties = new Dictionary<Property, Dictionary<int, string>>();
        properties.Add(Property.Brand, query);
```

Should return a json. But firstly need to get sequence. Json should look like:

```
[{
{"colors": [{"5", "Black"}, {"7", "White"}]}, 
{"brands": [{"78", "Q&Q"}, {"24", "Adidas"}]},
}]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a little textual (table) represantation of what you expect as a result?

Comment: see edit, i added how need to look json.

Comment: See the answer please

Comment: @Gert Arnold it is a PropertyValueId which represent row id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first GroupBy splits the list of `PropertyValues` by `PropertyId`, then this grouping is converted to a dictionary that has `PropertyId` as Key.

The values of each record of our dictionary is composed by creating a new dictionary where the key is `PropertyValueId` and the value is `Value`

```
PropertyValues.GroupBy( k => k.PropertyId )
    .ToDictionary( k => k.First().Value, 
          k => k.ToDictionary( p => p.PropertyValueId, p => p.Value ) );
```

Now data is structured as you want.

Comment: nice. and it works. i have tried to do the same but with  .Select( p => new KeyValuePair()) and every time it was crashed with exeption "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: @nickzdravcov Linq to entity tries to convert all expressions in sql.  The type KeyValuePair or is KeyValuePair(key,value) constuctor cannot be converted (not supported).